# Apache virtual host shows "index of" page instead of website

Tags: apache-http-server, django, mod-wsgi

Typing in the domain name in a brower shows the "index of /" page, instead of the content of my website. I'm using django, mod-wsgi and apache on ec2.

My apache conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 52.79.**.**:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/qna
Alias /m/ /var/www/qna/static/
Alias /upfiles/ /var/www/qna/askbot/upfiles/
<DirectoryMatch “/var/www/qna/askbot/skins/([^/]+)/media”>
Require all granted
</DirectoryMatch>
<Directory “/var/www/qna/askbot/upfiles”>
Require all granted
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess qna
WSGIProcessGroup qna
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/qna/django.wsgi
<LocationMatch “(?!/m)/admin(?!/media)”>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /admin(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/admin$1 [L,R=301]
</LocationMatch>
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/t_access_log common
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/qna_error_log
LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 52.79.**.**:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/qna
<LocationMatch "^(?!/admin)">
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule django.wsgi(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com$1 [L,R=301]
</LocationMatch>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/qna.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/qna.key
Alias /admin/media/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/media/
Alias /m/ /var/www/qna/static/
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/qna/django.wsgi
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/qna_access_log common
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/qna_error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

I am a newbie and I assume there is something fundamentally wrong with the apache setting. I've spent the last four days on this, tried everything to resolve this but solved nothing.

I assume that there is something wrong with WSGI setting because apache does not understand django. The settings.py file is in /var/www/qna.

Django 1.8.8 and Python 2.7.6, on Amazon ec2 Ubuntu. Thank you in advance. Please help.

I tried changing  to  and added ServerName mysite.com and also ServerAlias but in this case I get 500 Internal Server Error.

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/qna.conf:1)
*:443                  mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/qna.conf:31)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

But when I run `python maange.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` it works fine with no problem. I can access the website typing the domain name.

Comment: @Paul I don't have an index.html.

Comment: Ignore my comment about `DirectoryIndex`, I can see in Jake's reformatted config that there is an alias for /.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your configs; reformatted my me for readability:

```
<VirtualHost 52.79.**.**:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/qna

    Alias /m/ /var/www/qna/static/
    Alias /upfiles/ /var/www/qna/askbot/upfiles/

    <DirectoryMatch “/var/www/qna/askbot/skins/([^/]+)/media”>
        Require all granted
    </DirectoryMatch>

    <Directory “/var/www/qna/askbot/upfiles”>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess qna
    WSGIProcessGroup qna
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/qna/django.wsgi

    <LocationMatch “(?!/m)/admin(?!/media)”>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule /admin(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/admin$1 [L,R=301]
    </LocationMatch>

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/t_access_log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/qna_error_log

    LogLevel debug

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 52.79.**.**:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/qna

    <LocationMatch "^(?!/admin)">
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule django.wsgi(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com$1 [L,R=301]
    </LocationMatch>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/qna.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/qna.key

    Alias /admin/media/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/media/
    Alias /m/ /var/www/qna/static/

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/qna/django.wsgi

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/qna_access_log common
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/qna_error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

I am assuming if you have a virtual host setup in place, if you attempt to access the website via the IP address of `52.79.**.**:80` everything is fine, but if you are accessing it via a hostname/domain name like `example.com` then it is choking, correct? If that is the case what you need to do is set the virtual host lines like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

And this for HTTPS:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

Then *within* those config blocks you would set a `ServerName` value like this; of course this is not a full config but just a example of what you should change:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/qna

    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www example.* www.example.*
```

Doing something like this would allow the virtual host config to work correctly with `www.example.com` being the actual server name connected to that config and then `ServerAlias` allows the config to capture other variants of `www.example.com` such as `example.com` or `www.example.net`.

Answer (score 0):

The found the solution thanks to [Giacomo1968's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1035431/167207). Thank you so much, you saved my day!

It was rather simple, it was the permission issue.

As suggested, I checked `/var/log/apache2/qna_error_log`, and it said `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/qna/log/askbot.log'`

So I changed permission of `/var/www/qna/log` by using `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/` (I don't believe setting 777 is a good solution but I just did).

Now I got the following error:

```
ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.python-eggs'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

  /var/www/.python-eggs`
```

As suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107016/how-to-setup-up-python-egg-cache-environment-variable-on-mac), I made a new directory `/usr/local/pylons` and edited `django.wsgi` in `/var/www/qna` as below:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/usr/local/pylons/python-eggs'
```

And it's fixed! Now I see my website, not the "index of" page.